# How to connect to kubernetes-api from a browser?

Tags: docker, basic-authentication, kubernetes, tls1.2

I set up a cybernetes cluster this tutorial https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html

When you open the browser `https://my_ip` 
I get `Unauthorized`.

What you need to do to access the API?

~/kubectl config view`

`apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/hhh/ca.pem
    server: https://192.168.0.139
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: hhh-cluster
    user: hhh
  name: default-system
current-context: default-system
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: cluster-hhh
  user:
    password: admin
    username: admin
- name: default-admin
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/hhh/admin.pem
    client-key: /home/hhh/admin-key.pem`

basic-auth not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does basic auth work when using `kubectl` (it's unclear from your output which client credentials are working when connecting to your cluster's apiserver)?

Are you passing `--basic-auth-file` to your kube-apiserver process when starting it (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/server.go#L218)? If not, then basic auth will not work when connecting to your apiserver? If so, you can verify that it is working by running `curl -k --user admin:admin https://192.168.0.139`.

If you want (or need) to use client certificates from your browser, take a look at the instructions I put into [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7307#issuecomment-96130676) about making it easier to configure.